# html and css - Background image not working for some reason

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
    <section class="headers">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="HideMenu()"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="personal.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about2.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery2.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">BACK</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="ShowMenu()"></i>
        </nav>
        <div class="text-box">
            <h1>MEDIA STUDIES</h1>
            <p>A LEVEL
            </p>
            <a href="" class="hero-btn">ONENOTE</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```css
.headers{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/nlights.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Like I put the image in the right folder, and all I get is a white screen / no background.
Is there anyway to fix this?
[Not showing background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3HYG.png)

Comment: `background-image: url("images/nlights.jpg")` try adding quotes.

Comment: Tried it with the quotes but it seems that nothing happens. still a white background

Comment: Try the path `~/images/nlights.jpg`. It's not resolving the path to your image.

Comment: I have tested your code and everything is good. I'm pretty sure the problem is with your image URL. Have you checked your Console? Is there an error like this? ```Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND```

You can check your console on the developer tools -> inspects and there is a ```console``` tab. If you can see that error, it's from your image URL and you should change the URL and path it right.

Comment: Yeah I dont see that error code.

Comment: Taco タコス yeah still nothing, its soo weird

Comment: trying putting url for some other image. from net

Answer (score 1):

THANK YOU EVERYONE WHO TRY TO HELP ME WITH THIS PROBLEM !!!

All I had to do this clear my cache and cookie and it works

!!!